# Blender crashes when executing bpy.node.view_all(). How can I fix this?

Tags: python, scripting

When I try to execute bpy.node.view_all() within my code, Blender crashes. I'm attempting to override the Blender context to run `bpy.node.view_all()` or `bpy.node.view_selected()` in the shader editor, even though I'm in a different context. The issue arises when I use `bpy.node.select_all()`; it doesn't crash, but when I try the other code, it triggers a crash with an error message in the log.

`EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`

This is my code:

```
import bpy

shader_editor_area = None

for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
    for area in window.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'NODE_EDITOR' and area.ui_type == 'ShaderNodeTree':
            shader_editor_area = area
            print('Work')
            break

if shader_editor_area:
    print('Shader Editor Found')
    with bpy.context.temp_override(area= shader_editor_area):
        print('work')

        if bpy.ops.node.view_selected.poll():
            # If the poll function returns True, execute the operator
            print("this line of code don't work")
            bpy.ops.node.view_selected()
        else:
            print("Operator cannot be executed in this context.")

else:
    print("Shader Editor not found in another window.")
```

The issue arises when invoking `bpy.node.view_all()` or `bpy.node.view_selected()`, leading to a `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` error, resulting in Blender crashing.

I've attempted debugging by adding print statements within the function, and strangely, the function seems to work properly in that scenario.

Any insights into why this might be occurring or potential workarounds would be greatly appreciated.